# mdframed error missing begin{document}

Tags: errors, mdframed

I'm trying to use `mdframed` package. I had a problem running the file `Makefile` on ubuntu but I found and installed the `md-frame-0-1-2-3.mdf` files from another pc along with the `.cls` file

my code is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}    

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

and I got this [error file](http://pastebin.com/rLRKzh6d)

any help would be welcomed.

Comment: As Herbert says, your TeX distribution can't support the most recent version of `mdframed` that requires other packages to be more recent than you have. A TeX Live 2009 is really outdated.

Comment: @egreg: Can a TeXLive distribution be updated or someone has to reinstall it from scratch?

Comment: @Thanos Go to http://tug.org/texlive if you have a GNU/Linux box.

Comment: @egreg: `Due to the merge of the top-level texmf/ tree into texmf-dist, no upgrade procedure is viable in 2013, for either Unix or Windows. Please do a new install.` So I assume one has to reinstall it from scratch...

Comment: @Thanos The ‘vanilla’ TeX Live should never be upgraded. One does a new install and, when everything seems to work, the old release can be removed. You find several topics on this site regarding how to deal with a ‘vanilla’ TeX Live on GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Herbert and egreg commented, the problem was the old version of Latex. I'm using Linux Mint 13 (Maya), which is an LTS version, so when i installed the Latex, I got the package 2009.

I removed texlive from my computer, added the it's repository manually by

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
```

and then re-intalled it and got the version 2012. Now the package works fine.

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with current TeXLive 2013.
It looks like that your `mdframed` package is newer than the rest of your TeX installation. Put `\listfiles` as first line in your example and compare with my file list, which is at the end of the log file:

```
*File List*
book.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mdframed.sty 2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
xparse.sty 2013/11/19 v4609 L3 Experimental document command parser
expl3.sty 2013/11/19 v4610 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
l3names.sty 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
l3expan.sty 2013/08/17 v4584 L3 Argument expansion
l3tl.sty 2013/09/16 v4592 L3 Token lists
l3seq.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
l3int.sty 2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
l3quark.sty 2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
l3prg.sty 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Control structures
l3clist.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
l3token.sty 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
l3prop.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
l3msg.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
l3file.sty 2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
l3skip.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
l3keys.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
l3fp.sty 2013/11/18 v4601 L3 Floating points
l3box.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
l3color.sty 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty 2013/11/18 v4602 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etoolbox.sty 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
zref-abspage.sty 2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty 2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
auxhook.sty 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
needspace.sty 2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
color.sty 2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
md-frame-0.mdf 2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-0
graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
epstopdf-base.sty 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
grfext.sty 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
supp-pdf.mkii
***********
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my command line, I noticed:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 74, version
           `2011/01/03' of package etoolbox,
           but only version
           `2009/08/06 v1.8 e-TeX tools for LaTeX'
           is available.
```

In case you cannot or don't want to reinstall your LaTeX distribution, you can just get a new version of `etoolbox.sty` from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox?lang=en and put it in you project folder - mdframed will take it from there instead from the distribution installation...